# Can service-A expose a different mapped port to be accessed by service-B in docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, port

Suppose `container-A` is programed to listen on fixed port `8080`, is it possible to let `container-b` to access it by `http://service-a:80` in docker compose? a.k.a map the container port to a different port in the same network.

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  service-a:
    image: container-a
  service-b:
    image: container-b
```

Note that no ports are published on host.

BTW. in k8s, it's easier done with a service of port=80 & targetPort=8080.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can specify ports like :

**HOSTPORT:CONTAINERPORT**

```
services:
  service-a:
    image: container-a
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
  service-b:
    image: container-b
```

Comment: sorry, I don't want to expose 80 port on host